# WSO2 esb + AS feature = ESB can not manage HttpSession

Tags: wso2, httpsession, wso2-esb

this is my first question in Stackoverflow and i'm new in WSO2 ESB. I installed the 4.9.0 version of ESB and also installed Application Server feature on it. WSO2 ESB can not manage HttpSession. Can u help me please to solve this problem?
I already tried to change this parameter to true or false:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  <cookie-config>
   <secure>false</secure>
  </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

in ESB_HOME\repository\conf\tomcat\web.xml

Application server feature installed well i think. I can start my app and its working till i trying to use httpsession to manage users session and authentication. 
Somebody had the same problem?

Comment: Can you try to explain little bit more about your issue?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "cannot manage HttpSession"? What did you try to do?